# Ideapad 100s - can I change the battery info?

Tags: lenovo, battery

The battery info on the lenovo ideapad 100s is seriously messed up. Upower returns this:

```
upower -i $(upower -e)
```

> native-path:          BMBT
>     vendor:               SUNWODA
>     model:                NB116 1|CP4/58/145-2
>     serial:               123456789
>     power supply:         yes
>     updated:              Sat 23 Jul 2016 12:27:27 CEST (3 seconds ago)
>     has history:          yes
>     has statistics:       yes
>     battery
>       present:             yes
>       rechargeable:        yes
>       state:               discharging
>       warning-level:       none
>       energy:              0 Wh
>       energy-empty:        0 Wh
>       energy-full:         0 Wh
>       energy-full-design:  0 Wh
>       energy-rate:         0 W
>       percentage:          100%
>       capacity:            100%
>       technology:          lithium-ion
>       icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

And as a result the battery always shows up at 100%. Is there any way to fix this?